# Holding a function till user submits in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const onSubmit = ()=>{
 someFunction().then(()=>{
    // now wait for user to click on a button
    // something very similar to prompt() 
        
    // user clicked
    // do something
})
}
```

Here basically user initially when submit forms an function is executed which returns an promise where now .then() will wait for user to click on another button and then will execute the rest of code. Basically they way you do with alert/prompts the function does not executes till the user does not click on the ok/cancel. The only differnece is here it wont be the prompt but would be another button

P.S : I am using ReactJS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could write a function that returns a Promise that resolves or rejects according to whether confirm or cancel is clicked (or whatever) and have your onSubmit handler await that Promise.

```js
// just getting references to the dom elements we need so we can
// add listeners and such. necessary here but not really relevant
// to the solution.
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);
const el = document.querySelector('.confirm')
const confirmButton = el.querySelector('#confirmation');
const cancelButton = el.querySelector('#cancel');

async function onSubmit (e) {
  // stop the form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();
  
  try {
    // await confirmation
    await confirmation();
    
    // then do whatever you need to do.
    console.log('confirmed');
  }
  catch (e) {
    // confirmation() rejects on cancel, so do whatever
    // you need to do (maybe nothing at all) if the user
    // clicks cancel.
    console.log('canceled');
  }
}

function confirmation () {
  el.classList.add('visible');
  const hide = () => el.classList.remove('visible');
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    confirmButton.addEventListener('click', () => { hide(); resolve(); } );
    cancelButton.addEventListener('click', () => { hide(); reject(); } );
  });
}
```

```css
.confirm {
  display: none;
}

.confirm.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="confirm">
  <button id="confirmation">confirm</button>
  <button id="cancel">cancel</button>
</div>
```